# How to query non-assigned ForeignKeyField objects in models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have the following model & let's assume we have 5 `SouceCode` objects & 2 `Project` objects.

out of `5 SouceCode objects` i have added `2 objects` of SourceCode as `ForiegnKeyField to Project Model.`

Now, How do I print/query the `3 SourceCode objects` which haven't used as `ForeignKeyField for Project Model.`

---

**models.py**

```
class SourceCode(models.Model):
    source_description = models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True)
    source_urls = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True),),blank=True,null=True,default=list)
    source_results = JSONField(blank=True,null=True,default=dict)


class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    project_sourcecode_O2M = models.ForeignKey(SourceCode,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True)
```

---

One possible way I know is the following:

```
project_source_code_list = []
for each_project in Project.objects.all():
    project_source_code_list.append(each_project.project_sourcecode_O2M.source_description)

for each_source_code in SourceCode.objects.all():
    source_description = each_source_project.source_description
    if source_description not in project_source_code_list:
        print("YEP Not there")
```

---

I'm looking for a good alternative solution for this.

I would like to filter all non-assigned objects of `SourceCode` models & print `source_description` of that objects

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misreading the question, but it seems like all you want is the `SourceCode` objects which have empty reverse ForeignKey sets to the `Project` model:

```
descriptions = SourceCode.objects.filter(
    project__isnull=True
).values_list('source_description', flat=True)
```

Here the `filter` weeds out any `SourceCode` object connected to at least one project, and the `values_list` call pulls out the field you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is get the ID's of all the `SourceCode` objects, then subtract from that list all the `Project` objects which are assigned to `SourceCode`. For example;

```
# get the IDs of all SourceCode objects
source_ids = SourceCode.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)

# get the IDs of the SourceCode objects attached to a Project
linked_source_ids = Project.objects.values_list('project_sourcecode_O2M_id', flat=True)

# get the difference leaving the SourceCode IDs not linked to a Project
unassigned_ids = set(source_ids - linked_source_ids)

# get the SourceCode objects
unassigned_sourcecode = SourceCode.objects.filter(id__in=unassigned_ids)
```

Comment: ```unassigned_ids = set(source_ids - linked_source_ids)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet'```

Comment: @ArbazzHussain Force them to be lists then; `set(list(source_ids) - list(linked_source_ids))`